# Close votes review queue empty when filtered

Tags: bug, review-queues

I have a filter turned on in the Close votes review queue and the queue is empty (I only wish).

I am filtering on *Not suitable for this site, Needs details or clarity, Needs more focus, Opinion-based*, and the tags filter is empty.

[image]

When I clear the filter, then the queue functions normally.

---

Update: Actually, queue is not empty, but it takes about 30 seconds to show the question. When I click skip or apply vote I also need to wait same period of time for the next question. All other queues work fast.

Comment: [If your settings look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHuVA.png): I can't reproduce the problem. Filter works for me as expected. Do you have any scripts or styles, ... blocked?

Comment: The queue is cleared, thanks for helping out!

Comment: @BDL Yes. Exact same settings. I don't have any scripts or blockers, just vanilla Chrome. I am usually not going through close vote review queue, so I don't know whether this is a new thing or not.

Comment: Whatever the problem (is) was, it works fine at the moment. I will keep my eye on the queue for the next few days to see whether this is just "Sunday" fix or more permanent one.